# "2-way street" design

Tags: sql, database-design

I have a project that I have there "companies" and "employees" and I need to be able to "subscribe" for both of them.

So I thought to make it straightforward and make in my SQL tables a table for companies and then every company has employees inside of it.

The thing is, that there is a possibility that some employees are also "registered" to more then one company.

So it's like a 2-way street thingy and I wonder how can I arrange my SQL tables properly?

I need to be able to "subscribe" to a company as well as a single employee (and then to present all of its works in all the companies he worked).

Comment: Will the employee be working for more than one company at the same time?

Comment: @abhi yes . it is possible

Comment: what's wrong with the normal many-to-many solution of having 1 Employees table, 1 Companies table and 1 EmployeeWorksForCompany table?

Comment: also known as a [junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table)

Comment: the thing is that I need to be able to "subsribe" to a company as well as a single employee..(and then to present all of its works in all the companies he worked..)

Comment: When you subscribe to a single employee that works in more than one company, does the subscription apply to the employee in every company he works for, or does it apply to the employee in only one of the companies he works for?

Answer (score 1):

I would do this with 3 separate tables instead of 2.

Here's my **simplified** model of the database. Since I am currently logged on to SQL Server, I used that database.

```
CREATE TABLE company 
  ( 
     company_id   INT, 
     company_name NVARCHAR(100) 
  ); 

CREATE TABLE employee 
  ( 
     employee_id   INT, 
     employee_name NVARCHAR(100) 
  ); 

CREATE TABLE employment 
  ( 
     company_id  INT, 
     employee_id INT, 
     startdate   DATE, 
     enddate     DATE 
  );
```